# PaperJS how to set coordinate to (0, 0) after setZoom()

Tags: javascript, jquery, paperjs

Paper.js after using `setZoom()` the image goes out of bounds, how to tie the zoom to the left top `coordinate (0 , 0),` so that the image is zoomed from it?
Actual result on setZoom(85):

[image: Actual]

Expected result, when image on `coordinates (0, 0):`

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 0):

I found, that I need to add my method to paper.js.

```
setZoomToTopLeft: function (zoom)
{
    this.transform(new Matrix().scale(zoom / this.getZoom(),
        new Point(0, 0)));
},
```